SQLite - Design use of Variable Length Integers - explain the design flaw
The Carnegie Mellon Database Group invited the creator of sqlite D. Richard Hipp to talk about SQLite - The Databaseology Lectures - CMU Fall 2015.
Richard Hipp shows this slide (~ 39m51s) and says the following (copied from transcript)

We use Variable Length Integers. And this is
the variable length integer encoding where it just it reads bytes that
have 0 in the high order bit and uses the 7 lower bits or it uses the
entire 9th I in order to construct your own integers and this was a
mistake. And I give you this this is this is a failure. So if you're
ever doing something like this and you need variable length integers
don't do them this way instead do them like this where the first byte
tells you you know the magnitude of the integer somehow or another


Update
I am aware that Mr. Hipp shows this slide next

And he says

and the reason for doing it this way is the first byte determines the size of the variable an integer which is very important for efficiency in parsing this.
And the other thing is that you can actually compare two integers using MIM compare without having to decode them

But i do not understand why this is more efficient. I assume that less bytes are needed to compare and doing less is faster. But i do not know anything about MIM compare.
gnat linked below How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}? and this snippet illustrates my problem:

So how would you explain pointers to a peer in computing? If you do
not understand pointers fully yourself, the question will turn from
how do you explain them to someone else to the community explaining
them to you.

Question
Can someone explain eli5 why Richard Hipp considers this design a mistake?

What is the problem?
What other solution would be better?


i mean... if you listen for literally 5 more seconds he tells you?

"eli5" -- see How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?

The problem is that this makes it necessary to decode each byte in sequence. You cannot skip ahead. You cannot parallelize anything. Other variable length encodings (including UTF-8) encode the length of the number in the first byte.

"MIM compare" is a failed transcription of "memcmp", which should help if you want to look it up

The major reason this is more efficient is not number of comparisons, but path data dependency. On modern pipelined OOO cpus, making a conditional branch based on data from memory is one of the more expensive things you can do. With the sqlite encoding how you process each byte depends on the previous. You can't resolve the control flow until that byte has been read and parsed.
By comparison? With Hipps encoding, as soon as you've processed the first byte, you know the entire path. Any additional control flow in parsing the integers depends purely on registers, and doesn't need to wait on memory. You can resolve all the branches and even start executing the instructions after the parsing loop before you read the second byte from the integer, because you know which instructions will be executed.

If i understood Out of Order execution (OoO) correctly then this matches what amon commented  above: The problem is that this makes it necessary to decode each byte in sequence. You can't skip ahead. You can't parallelize anything And since Hipp said you can actually compare two integers using memcompare without having to decode them i assume that int memcmp(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2, size_t num); would be faster since it only need to compare the first byte?!

@surfmuggle That is all correct

As @Ewan says in his comment, Hipp himself gives the answer a few seconds later: efficiency.
It's essentially the analogy of the issues with variable-length strings, and the difference between null-terminating and length-prefixing.
The advantage of one or the other very much depends on the typical handling of the data and the characteristics of the machine, but there seems to be a definite tendency over the decades towards length-prefixing as the most computationally efficient mode.
I vaguely remember (iirc...) Dennis Ritchie explaining why they adopted null-terminating as the default in C, and it basically came down to their subjective impression at the time that null-terminating was easier to program with.
There seems to be a more general principle though, that knowing the length of variable data up-front contributes massively to the efficiency of handling on average, and if it can't be known at compile-time as a fixed-length field, then the next-best option is maintaining a length-prefix for the data (which should itself be either a fixed-length sub-field, or a length-prefixed sub-field, this logic applying recursively to the prefix as much as to the main data it measures).

Where nowadays using null terminating strings generally is considered a design mistake.

@JoopEggen, I assume in the early 70s it was implicit that most individual strings would have been small, and if you were doing anything unusually heavy there'd have been some kind of navigable structure overlaid on the data (like fixed-width blocks used in file systems), or a special approach taken (e.g. length prefixing) on a per-case basis. Even in the 90s, filenames for example were still 11 chars max. Everything was a lot more economical.

Can you elaborate how the efficiency is achieved and what role MIM compare plays?

@surfmuggle, I'm not sure what "MIM compare" is? The basic efficiency is in the fact that you don't have to scan the string char-by-char to find its length each time it's read, only once when the string is first entered/parsed. Strings have definitely got longer since the 70s, hence the cost of re-scanning on each read has grown whereas the cost of maintaining a prefix hasn't, but many other circumstances have changed too (like security/reliability concerns about buffer overruns in main memory).

@surfmuggle, with the additional context edited into your question, I agree that "MIM compare" is some kind of mistranslation of "memcompare" (the spoken name of the C function memcmp, as seen in the added slide). What Hipp seems to be saying is that his approach has the property of sorting correctly with a native binary comparison (i.e. the fastest comparison possible).

@Steve DOS filenames were 11 characters max. Neither Mac OS or any Unix variant I was familiar with at the time had such a small limitation. (I'm almost certainly misremembering the details, but I think Mac OS allowed for 255-charaters paths, and Unix file systems typically allowed arbitrarily long paths as long as no path component exceeded 255 characters.) Even Windows tried to hide the DOS limit from the user.

@chepner, point was that if people were still making do with 11 char max filenames in the mid-90s, then you can imagine how long typical strings were for Ritchie in the early 70s when he decided that re-parsing the string for the length every time was the best balance of all concerns. Of course, the 11 char max limit in DOS was an example of fixed-width overlay - a sentinel-terminated string has no intrinsic limit.
